# function call not returning to correct location

Tags: c, pic

struggling with what should be a simple function call and return (PIC micro, XC16 compiler). The return seems to go to the wrong location as if the program counter is not storing its value properly. Probably finger trouble on my part.

Function to determine the status of a switch (if switch held closed continue with output sequence, otherwise wait), not the best programming, I know.

```
void check()               //check the switch status to continue or stop sequence
{
  if (PORTFbits.RF2==0)    //If the switch is closed then start time check
  {
    __delay_ms(500);
    if (PORTFbits.RF2==0)  //If the switch is still closed after 0.5s then resume sequence
    {
      return ;
    }
  }                         
  check();                 // otherwise loop, wait for next switch close
}
```

In the main function sequence some outputs (in a while loop)-

```
LATDbits.LATD0 = 1;
SaveD = LATD;                 // Save the status of the outputs
check();                      // Check the switch status
__delay_ms(500);
LATD = 0;
LATDbits.LATD1 = 1;
SaveD = LATD;
check();
__delay_ms(500);
LATD = 0;
LATDbits.LATD2 = 1;
check();
```

The check() function is being called but the return goes back to the first instruction in main rather than executing the next instruction after the function call.

Am I doing something silly?

Regards
Active

Comment: Have you heard of "recursion"? This is what your function does. Not loop as stated.

Comment: Thanks, a little help to understand that appreciated.

Comment: the function is calling itself. Thus every time it is entering from it's start. And it will do it until your stack is overflowing unless the termination condition (that `PF2` thing) will be met. No you should read about recursion elsewhere.

Comment: Some PICs have a hardware call stack only 8 levels deep. When it overflows, the processor resets.

Comment: Recursion: your function calls itself.  This is not the same thing as looping, you do not need it for your purposes, and it is risky for you, especially in a microcontroller context where you may be operating with a small(ish) stack.  C has `for` and `while` constructs with which you can implement *bona fide* loops.

Comment: Does your PIC compiler implement tail recursion? If not, the recursive call will use up the stack space.   About returning to the first instruction in `main`; might it be possible that that's happening due to a device reset?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Calling yourself is the same thing as looping, if you're in a tail recursive language (like Scheme and various functional languages). C isn't that language, but some compilers have the optimization that effectively turns their local dialect into one, at least for some programs.

Comment: @Kaz Not every recursion is tail recursion. This one is...

Comment: @Kaz recursion is not the same thing as looping at the language level, regardless of what any given compiler does with it.  Not even in languages that have only recursion, not iteration, to draw upon.  This is a distinction that should not be obscured.

Comment: Note that I tried a while beforehand and this just disregards the switch status     while (PORTFbits.RF2==0)
{
        return;

Comment: That's because you are not using it properly...

Comment: @Active, we cannot evaluate code you have not presented.  I observe, however, that even apart from the recursion, your present code looks questionable.  If it executes the recursive call at all, it will do so immediately after `PORTFbits.RF2` evaluates to nonzero.  The first thing the recursive execution of the function then does is check the same condition again, which is probably unchanged because physical controls move at a rate measurable in millions of cycles.  You will get very deep recursion, very rapidly.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem stems from the fact that you are likely overflowing your stack.

Consider your code:

```
void check()               //check the switch status to continue or stop sequence
{
  if (PORTFbits.RF2==0)    //If the switch is closed then start time check
  {
    __delay_ms(500);
    if (PORTFbits.RF2==0)  //If the switch is still closed after 0.5s then resume sequence
    {
      return ;
    }
  }                         
  check();                 // otherwise loop, wait for next switch close
}
```

In the case where `PORTFbits.RF2 != 0` you will immediately fall through to the next call to `check()`.

This means that in one or two instructions, you are recursing (when a function calls itself, that is named *recursion* - the function is a *recursive* function, it *recurses* on itself, etc.).

So, in a very small amount of time, you could have tens, hundreds, or thousands of calls to the `check()` function.

Each of those calls will *push* the return address of the call onto the stack, consuming stack space. Eventually, as some commenters have pointed out, you'll either crash the machine entirely, or force a reset. Forcing a reset will restart your code in `main`, as you have seen.

As written, your code will not return from the outermost `check()` call until the switch is closed. Assuming that is what you want, here's some code that might work:

```
void wait_for_switch()
{
     while (1) {
         if (PORTFbits.RF2 == 0) {  /* Switch is closed. */
             __delay_ms(500);       /* Debounce interval. */
             if (PORTFbits.RF2 == 0) return; /* Still closed? Done! */
         }
         else {
             /* Wait for switch to close. */
             __delay_ms(100);
         }
     }
  }
```

**UPDATE:**

Hearing that your compiler isn't reloading the switch bits, led me to this alternative. I suspect that the first read of the bits in the function will work, so let's just put the port read into a function:

```
int read_portfbits_rf2() {
    return PORTFbits.RF2;
}

void wait_for_switch()
{
     while (1) {
         if (read_portfbits_rf2() == 0) {  /* Switch is closed. */
             __delay_ms(500);       /* Debounce interval. */
             if (read_portfbits_rf2() == 0) return; /* Still closed? Done! */
         }
         else {
             /* Wait for switch to close. */
             __delay_ms(100);
         }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Austin, have already tried something similar to your code (and also copied your code) but the sequence continually runs through to the end (effectively disregarding multiple function calls except for the 'last one'). Something similar written in assembler is working. Beyond my rather poor software knowledge.

Comment: Is the `PORTFbits` object declared `volatile`?

Comment: I think port bits are volatile and so they are set with pragma, TRIS etc. I even use two persistent attributes just in case and then test those. I have reverted to assembler for the time being and this is working correcty.. There seems to be something fundamentally wrong with function calls when using PIC24 with XC16

Comment: @Active, it is much more likely that there is something wrong with *your functions* than that there is something wrong with function *calls*.  Whether Austin's code or your own similar code does as you want is not directly relevant to that, not least because he's *guessing* at what the functionality is that you require (or else he's a lot more insightful than I am, which is possible).

Comment: @Active can you dump the assembly generated by the compiler? That would be a good place to start.

Comment: @Active: see update - if you read the bits in a separate function, does that help?

Comment: FWIW: Reading the XC16 compiler manual [here](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MPLAB_XC16_v1_10_C_Compiler_UG_52081.pdf) seems to indicate that `volatile` is supported, and works for reading port values.

Comment: The issue seems to be returning from a function (almost as if the program counter is confused / has lost its location) so I have reverted to the assembler equivalent due to time constraints and will investigate later. Thanks for all your help.